# Connecting to multiple databases in java

Tags: database, jdbc, connection

I'm trying to create a method that allows me to connect to a database. Since it can be use more than one different database **I was trying to create a generic method** that receives the database connection as String and connect to that database.

```
public static Connection ConnectingDB(String urlConnection) throws SQLException {
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("??");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("??:"+ urlConnection);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
        return c;
    }
```

What should I put in `Class.forname` and in `DriverManager.getConnection()`?

Answer (score 0):

I've implement the same kind of things using custom qualifier.

If you have define a jdbc Datasource on your server. In J2EE with annotation,
you can define a custom qualifier and a resource producer that will instantiate your different Datasource.

I have asked this question 3 month ago and i have managed to do it :

[Custom qualifiers on interface doesn't work on injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788646/custom-qualifiers-on-interface-doesnt-work-on-injection)

Hope it helps you